# is there a way to embed youtube videos using a custom NON FLASH skin so it is supported on my regular and mobile site?

Tags: flash, html, mobile, youtube, skin

i would like to have a custom interface ( less ugly than the generic youtube skin ) and have it work on my site which needs to be accessible via regular browser and ipad.  long story short - i want NO FLASH on my site.  can i support you tube embedded videos without their ugly player and without the using a flash work around?  JW Player from LongtailVideo is flash still but otherwise seems to work.  Any suggestions?  html5 solutions?  thanks!

Comment: JWPlayer "is flash" but has a HTML5 fallback and that's why it works.

Comment: so i can create a skin to look nothing like the youtube player(for example make the sliders look like a football if i wanted to) using JWPlayer and it will simply fall back to HTML5 when called on?  thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

try this
http://www.youtube.com/html5

Join the HTML5 Trial and you can see all videos with html5.